# Backup database with filtered data

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have a database where I have data of several enterprises.
The database is in Postgres.

Now I want a way to generate database backup with filtered data for each enterprises.

I have got a few solutions but is none of them data can be filtered, direct back up of database is possible but I want it filtered

What is the best way to do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Backup the whole database, restore it somewhere else, remove the data you don't want, backup again.

Comment: No the client want to download there data as a backup. No customization, just a single click command to generate filtered database backup

Comment: Write code that does the above and hide it behind a button that runs it in a single click.

Comment: Obviously that will be required, but how to make a database out of it is my question